# How to check DB records with PHP from HTML Form

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I`m not experienced in programing, but i have a problem about fetching data from database with PHP using HTML form 'method=POST'.

My goal is getting an email from DB using HTML form and displayed it in numbers, like, how many specified email address`es (in html form - ) has been found on DB.
I want to display email records from DB in html/php page as numbers how many found e.g 5, 24, 82 etc.

So far i have done this:
I have used the DB command code

```
SELECT email, COUNT( email ) Total
FROM table_name
GROUP BY email
HAVING Total >1;
```

Output result was this:

```
email                    Total
app@gmail.com                7
yoyo@gmail.com              13
yoyoaa@gmail.com             3
yoyoadade@gmail.com          3
yoyoaga3@gmail.com           3
yoyoas@gmail.com             3
yoyoassdf@gmail.com          3
```

The 3, 7 and 13 was output results with duplicated email addresses that was found on database.

This is the PHP code i have done so far and it's not working, it doesn't give me the results i want:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("db_host", "db_username", "password", "db_name");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$sql = "SELECT email, COUNT( email ) Total\n"
. "FROM table_name\n"
. "GROUP BY email\n"
. "HAVING Total >1";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
echo "Found: $row['email']; ',' email addresses in the database.";
} else {
echo "Email address have no records in database.";
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

..and form code i`m using for POST method to get the specified email address counts from the database:

```
<form action='?getdata' method='post'>Enter email: <input type='text'    name='email' id='email'><br><input type='submit' name='submit' value=' Check records '></form>
```

Hope to solve this problem soon. I have searched over the internet about the same problem peoples have, but no exact results i needed found.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Ryder :)

Comment: How is the output incorrect?  Can you show your `$sql = ""` string?
NM, it's at the top.  Hard to tell what's going wrong, can you show output data vs what is expected/actual in the db?

Comment: I`m sorry forgot about that string. Now post has been edited.

Comment: You're executing the query, but you're not doing anything with the result set. See this [quick start guide](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

@Matt Jacob is correct.  You need to iterate through the results to print them out.

```
$sql = "SELECT email, COUNT( email ) Total\n"
. "FROM table_name\n"
. "GROUP BY email\n"
. "HAVING Total >1";
$raw_results = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){ 
      // sorry I don't know msqli just yet(on my list)
      // Use the mysqli equivelant for fetch_array
      $email = $row['email'];
      $count = $row['count( email )'];

      print "$email has $count occurences<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Nop this sample (comined with my codes) didn't worked as i wanted, but i appreciate your help. :)

I hope you guys got my idea what exactly i want to get using FORM submit option?

If not, i can explain it again. So, let's say i have a simple html form with one textarea and submit button. When in the textarea has been entered any email and button clicked the PHP code should check Database for Duplicates of this email. If found email the array should show number of counts how many duplicates of this entered email have in the DB, like this, simple but i`m stuck. :(
Thanks